# How to get modal presented view controller's root view height?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

For a view controller like the *Settings* one shown in the below image, how to get the height of a view controller's view without any dependency to the AutoLayout?

Is there any system variable or macro we can use like `UIScreen.main.bounds.size` to get the
screen size?

AutoLayout is not good to me since I need to pre-calculate the frames for further display.

[image: demo]

Comment: Does `view.bounds.height` work?

Comment: can you mention what is the purpose for knowing this height?, may be we could come up with some other solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. First get the current view height by `view.frame.height`
2. Then get the main screen height (device screen height) by `UIScreen.main.bounds.height`
3. After that **Subtract** current view height from thr main screen height.

Below is the sample code:-

```
let currentViewHeight:CGFloat = view.frame.height
let mainScreenHeight:CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
let heightYouNeed = mainScreenHeight-currentViewHeight
```

Here **view** is the UIView that is being presented.

Comment: It works when you calculate heights in viewWillAppear. viewDidLoad is return wrong result

Answer (score 1):

At which point do you need it to be calculated? I think the previous answers suggesting to subtract `UIScreen.main.bounds.height - view.frame.height` should be taken with precaution, because in `viewDidLoad` the actual frame will be different than in `viewDidAppear`